# Intent and string array

Tags: android

I need pass a string array from AlarmReceiver.class to Notify.class but the string is always "null". Now, is a problem about intent within AlarmReceiver?

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
[...]
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("com.example.myapp", null, context, Notify.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1[x]);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

Notify class:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent notificationIntent = getIntent();
      String[] message = notificationIntent.getStringArrayExtra("notify");
Toast toast6=Toast.makeText(this,""+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast6.show();
```

Comment: What are the declarations for `not1` and `x`?

Comment: You are mixing string array with a plain string. which do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using two different methods...

1. Here you're are working with one String:

   ```
   notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1[x]); // Pass one String
   ```

   You should read this `"notify"` with:

   ```
   String message = notificationIntent.getStringExtra("notify");
   ```
2. If you want to pass the array of Strings use:

   ```
   notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", not1); // Pass array of Strings
   ```

   You should read this with:

   ```
   String[] message = notificationIntent.getStringArrayExtra("notify");
   ```

Do you see the difference?

Comment: Or the other way around, `putExtra("notify", not1);` as it seems the question asks about sending an array. Not that it is used that way so a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks Sam! You're always so gentle! :-)

Comment: Sam: what it the best way to cancel notify after click on it?

Comment: You can call [`NotificationManager#cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel%28int%29), using the id that you used in `notify()`.